# sed - search and replace between 2 marks

Tags: string, bash, shell, command-line, sed

I want to search a String and modify it

I build a String like that:

```
|Bor.Team1-FCTeam2|
```

but also:

```
|FCTeam2-Bor.Team1|
```

or as pattern

```
|Text–Text|
```

I want to change the Name of Team1, it can have different Names eg:

```
Bor.Team1
B.Team1
BTeam091
...
```

I want everytime the same name -> `B.Team1`

`Team` is everytime IN the different diction!

I play arround with `sed 's/\bBor.Team1\b/B.Team1/g'`, but I must find and know every different diction.

Comment: what about the `BTeam091` have to do with `Team1` in your sample ? Could you provide a sample of entry and expected result (especialy about the `|Text-Text|` pattern to find ?

Answer (score 0):

That shoudl do what you need:

```
echo $string | sed -e 's/[a-zA-Z\.]\+Team\([0-9]\+\)/B.Team\1/g'
```

It searches for alphabetic characters and also a dot (`.`) followed by the word `Team`, followed by a number (`[0-9]`). That all will be replaced by whatever you want. In the example it's `B.Team` followed by the found number (`\1`).

Answer (score 0):

find and replace any something `Team1` d replace the whole by `B.Team1` and keep counter part the same in each `| |` surrounded content

```
sed -e 's/\|[^-|]*Team1[^-|]*-\([^|]*\)|/|B.Team1-\1|/g
        s/\|\([^-|]\)-[^|]*Team1[^|]*|/|\1-B.Team1|/g' YourFile
```

ex:

- |bla.team1.corp-other| -> |B.team1-other|
- |ot.her-foolteam1| -> |ot.her-B.team1|